# ServiceController service name too long for constructor

Tags: windows-services

Oracle has seem to have done something that should not be possible (IMHO) :)

I have a service from Oracle (I think, don't shoot me, I'm just the developer!)

Name = "Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse NodeManager (C_Oracle_Middleware_Home_wlserver_12.1)"

All 87 chars. When I try to determine the services depended on by using a System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.get_ServicesDependedOn() call, I get an exception stating

> "Service name Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse NodeManager
>   (C_Oracle_Middleware_Home_wlserver_12.1) contains invalid characters,
>   is empty, or is too long (max length = 80)"

This name is the name of the registry key for the service as well. My understanding is that this property (Name on Win32_Service class), is supposed to be limited to 80 chars.

Makes it real hard to use ServiceController class when the constructor barfs on the invalid, yet successfully installed service. -__-

My quick fix, because I have to ship code tomorrow, is to trunc any service name I get down to 80 chars and call it the "Hail Mary Fix".

Have any of you found a way around this that is better? I cannot control how loose Windows seems to be on this field, and service developers (Oracle) not adhering to an 80-char limit on service short name.

Help me , Obi-Wan! ;)

Comment: Just realized...this approach will not work. If I trunc the name to get the constructor to work, the call to get the Property ServicesDependedOn may fail...testing now...

Comment: yep, it blew chunks when trying to access the property. There would seem to be no way around this, to me, beyond repairing the obvious hole in the service short name via some MS-supported means.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably going to have to find another way. I decompiled the ServiceController and I found a method that has the 80 character check baked in. You could shell out to the sc.exe or something instead.

```
// System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController
internal static bool ValidServiceName(string serviceName)
{
    if (serviceName == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (serviceName.Length > 80 || serviceName.Length == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    char[] array = serviceName.ToCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        char c = array[i];
        if (c == '\\' || c == '/')
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: 80 characters is the limit in both 2.0 and 4.0 versions of the DLL.